# SSRS Subscriptions - Daily Emails Within a Time Interval

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I need to setup a subscription to an SSRS report that I have, so it would send emails Daily between 5PM and 5AM only. Is this supported by SSRS 2005 or 2008?

My only option right now is to set up 12 different copies of the report and have 12 different subscriptions, for 5PM, 6PM, 7PM...4AM, 5AM etc. I don't like this approach for the maintenance complexity it adds.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Nandun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not through Report Manager; you've already seen that you have limited options there.

However, when you set up an SSRS subscription, behind the scenes it's just set up as a normal SQL Server job run through the SQL Server Agent - these jobs are set up under a GUID type name, i.e. something like `8DF42130-97D3-41F7-B3EF-72E48BFDFBFA`.

This means that you can update the job schedule in Management Studio with a few more options:

[image]

You should be able to update a SSRS created subscription to suit your requirements.

Not sure why you can't just do this through Report Manager, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Wow.. i did not know this. thanks. I'm not sure why but report manager doesn't let you specify an end time to a schedule.

Comment: I agree it's very strange... Just another SSRS quirk to add to the list. If you do give this a try please update with the results!

Comment: This works perfectly. thank you. However i haven't tried modifying the subscription from reports manager. not sure what exactly would happen.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update! Your guess for how Report Manager would handle this is as good as mine...